# How to get value in dataframe columns that contains multi-value item

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns like this :

[colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sryoK.png)

how to get individual value from the column ?

desired output is list ex: [42008598,26472654,42054590,42774221,42444463], so it value(s) can be counted

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an advice: when you have some example code to show us, It would be great if you paste into the code quotes `like this`. It is easiest to read. Let's go with your question. You can select row in a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
print(df.iloc[i])
```

where `i` is the row number: `0, 1, 2,...` and `df` is your dataframe. Here is the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

I am also new in Stackoverflow. I hope this could help you.

Comment: I think his variable is like a long string with numbers, for example, "{1, 3, 5, 7}" and he wants to do the operation with the numbers inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to convert each row in the dataframe to an array and then do the operation that you want with this array. The way you can do it with Pandas would be to declare a function that deals with each row, and them use apply to run the function each row.

An example to count how many elements has inside each row:

```
def treat_array(row):
    row = row.replace("{", "")
    row = row.replace("}", "")
    row = row.split(",")
    return len(row)

df["Elements Count"] = df["Name of Column with the Arrays"].apply(treat_array)
```